# Vertical-align text within a nav bar

Tags: html, css, height, line, vertical-alignment

EDIT: problem solved

I am having trouble vertically aligning the two menu options on the right with the main `heading` on the left. I want the bottom of both lines of text to sit flush with each other.

**jsfiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/f1pant3a/

**Like so**:

[image: like_so]

**At the moment** they are sitting like this:

[image]

Comment: you want 'interact' and 'photo' under 'spray city'  as a list?

Comment: please state your points cearly, so we don't go around reading your question 3 times, not understanding it still

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: hi guys, sorry the question wasn't clear, I would like the bottom of all the text in the navigation bar to be aligned, rather than how it is currently - where the bottom of the two menu options on the right are higher than the bottom of the title on the left. (the space between the image and the right options is larger than the space between the image and the title on the left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` fixes your problem:

[image]

Or if you don't want to give it to all the elements, as suggested by [klaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147246/klaar), you can give this:

```
img {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f1pant3a/5/**

> ***Note:*** This is an issue with improper use of `width` and box model properties. You need to be careful in selecting those.

This would be a small illustration to understand how the box model works:

[image]
<sub>(source: [teamtreehouse.com](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/box-model-illustration.png))</sub>

Comment: That's a bit overkill. Just give `div.image` and `div.image img` that property and value.

Comment: @klaar Check out the updated answer please.

Comment: Sure, but some more information as to when you'd choose to do it and when it'd be a bad decision would be nice. Just writing directives is not the way to teach someone properly. But that's just my view. ;-)

Comment: @klaar Give me some time to post the explanation buddy.

Comment: I was not aware of the way of working here on SO: put a framework-answer containing almost nothing except the bare minimum and later expanding it to gain attraction. Now I do, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @klaar What do you think? Is it good or bad? Everything is just a personal preference buddy.

Comment: Sure, it's good. Maybe something about the default value of the box-sizing property and also the meaning of each value would be the cherry on the cake. +1 if you manage that!

Comment: @klaar Yes, Let me do that and get a +1 from you.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you, that helped immensely!